# How to compare a logistic regression ad-click predictor against a random predictor?

Tags: regression, logistic, likelihood

**Set up:** assume we have a set of $n$ diverse ads and a single website, which serves as our advertising space. Whenever a user visits this website, he is shown a *single* ad from our set, and if he clicks on it we count that as a success.

**Problem:** how to choose the best ad to show? By "the best" I mean the one with the highest probability of a click. I should also note that regardless of whether the user might be interested in any of our ads or not, we MUST display one of the ads.

**First attempt:** I tried out a logistic regression model:
$$ \hat{p}_{t}(\mathbf{w}_t, \mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{1+\exp[-\mathbf{w}_t \cdot \mathbf{x}]},$$
with online gradient descent, i.e. at each step/observation $y_t$ suffering the log-loss associated with displaying ad $j$ with the highest probability $\hat{p}_{t}(\mathbf{w}_t, \mathbf{x}^j)$:
$$ \textrm{Log-loss}_t(\mathbf{w}_t) =  -y_t \log \hat{p}_{t}(\mathbf{w}_t, \mathbf{x}^j) - (1-y_t)\log (1-\hat{p}_t(\mathbf{w}_t, \mathbf{x}^j)),$$
where $y_t$ is either 1 (user decided to *read more*), or 0 (no action). The feature vector $\mathbf{x}^j$ contains features describing the user, and features referring to ad $j$.

To optimize the parameters $\mathbf{w}_t$, I modify them after each observation (after displaying the $j^\text{th}$ ad) using a gradient of the $\textrm{Log-loss}_t$ function.

Thus, I arrive at a model $\hat{p}$ predicting the probability of a click.

After tweaking various parameters of my model (features, learning rate of the online gradient descent, and other), I chose the one with the lowest $\textrm{Log-loss}$, as calculated on a validation set. Its test $\textrm{Log-loss}$ was around $0.022$ (to be fair, all models had very similar, very low values of the error metric).

**Alas:** when testing my model "live", on the actual website, it performed slightly better than a random-choice-model (each ad chosen with a probability $1/n$). I verified the code, and it's safe to assume that this surprisingly poor performance is not due to a coding error.

The $y_t = 1$ class is very rare (say, one in $10^5$ users decides to click an ad). As a consequence, my model estimates very low probabilities ($~10^{-5}$), which yields a low $\textrm{Log-loss}$.

**THE ACTUAL QUESTION:**
I would like to compare my models against the random-choice-model.

If I had plugged the $1/n$ probability into the $\textrm{Log-loss}$ I wouldn't get a reliable assessment of the random-choice-model.

So, my first thought was to figure out a re-scaling of the random-choice probability. Or, to find a skew-insensitive error metric (perhaps this would be the best solution, and I'm open to suggestions regarding this scenario).

But then, I had a very different idea: to train my model by minimizing a modified $\textrm{Log-loss}$ function, e.g.:

$$\textrm{Log-loss2}_t(\mathbf{w}_t) := \textrm{Log-loss}_t(\mathbf{w}_t) + 1-(\sum_{k=1}^n \hat{p}_{t}(\mathbf{w}_t, \mathbf{x}^k))^2,$$

where I use a regularization term, keeping the probabilities normalized. This way, I hope to:

1. compare my models with the random-choice-model;
2. incorporate probability estimates for all ads into the error function.

The second points seems appealing, since whenever $y_t$ is $0$, the parameters $\mathbf{w}_t$ would change so that the probability of the ad displayed would decrease, but at the same time -- increase the probabilities of the remaining ads.

**Follow-up questions:** am I trying to re-invent the wheel? Are there any obvious counter-arguments to constructing a custom log-loss error measure?

Comment: The problem of 'choosing the best ad to show' sounds to me like a Design of Experiments problem. You'd set up a test design, display ads randomly until you collect statistically sufficient sample sizes, and then analyze the test results to determine which test performed significantly better than others.

Comment: That's a good point. However, the set of ads is dynamically changing (beyond my control), as well as the audience of the website. At any given time, some of the ads are well-tested, and some - although much fewer - are "new", in the sense that I haven't had the chance of displaying them.

Comment: a) can you confirm you have an intercept or bias term.  b) I would just use regular logistic regression with L2 regularisation rather than on line gradient descent. The l2 regularisation puts a penalty on coefficients (ie only deviate from average if there are sufficient samples). c) look at relative deviance to the null model(ie the log loss over the log loss of the intercept only model - ie give all ads the average CTR) [google pseudo R squared ?]. d) I agree with @Vishal, but would point you though to thompson sampling/bayesian bandits which has a more 'online' approach

Comment: a) I confirm, there is an intercept; b) I figured I needed online gradient descent because of the amount of data about the website's visitors, but regardless: I didn't use the L2 regularization because my coefficients were not that large, mostly within a [-2, 2] interval. Do you think I should try it, nonetheless? c) That's a very good idea, I will need to try it out; d) Thompson sampling - that's something I haven't heard of so far, and it seems it might be valuable. I'll give it some thought and test your suggestions, and provide you with some feedback.

Comment: @seanv507's suggestion to look into Thompson sampling / bayesian bandits was spot on. However, it seems that the question "how to test my model against a random baseline" would also apply to a bayesian bandits model. I've posted this question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203638/how-to-compare-two-models-for-the-multi-armed-bandit-problem-based-on-historica